# Material-UI - возможно ли вывести CSS в отдельный файл?

Tags: css, reactjs, material-design, material-ui

В мир фронтенда попал не по своей воле. Начал изучать React. Понравился Material-UI. Так как он все стили напрямую пишет в отрендеренный HTML, то возник вопрос:

Возможно ли вывести CSS стили в отдельный файл?